# File "has unexpected contents" error when sideloading Android 5.0 OTA zip file

Tags: adb, 5.0-lollipop, ota-update, side-loading

I have a Nexus 7 (2013) (wifi) and am trying to update the software to Android 5.0. When I try to sideload, I get this error:

```
Installing update...
mount: failed to mount /dev/block/platform/msm.sdcc.1/by-name/system at /system: Invalid argument
Verifying current system...
"/system/app/Drive.apk" has unexpected contents.
E: Error in /tmp/update.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
```

How I did it:

I placed the OTA file in `sdk/platform-tools` folder. Then I opened up a command prompt and typed in `adb sideload 5a0f7a47588c268c239e58cf568823c6637c5af1.signed-razor-LRX21P-from-KTU84P.5a0f7a47.zip` and I got that error.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It seems to think you've modified your original ROM. Are you rooted? Did you uninstall or disable the Google Drive app?

Comment: What do you mean by disable the Google Drive app? @eldarerathis

Comment: Based on the filename, looks like it's the [official stock OTA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/ref-nexus-7-stock-ota-urls.1745781/post-56729250).

Answer (score 1):

This means that recovery doesn't recognize the Google Drive APK inside the update package. Most ROMs don't come with Google Drive pre-installed, so I assume you're trying to use a factory image, which needs to be decompressed and flashed via fastboot. Factory images cannot be installed via recovery.

First, you'll need the Android SDK. Here is a link to get that: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Next, you'll need to unlock the bootloader. Power down your Nexus 7 and then hold power + volume down until it boots into fastboot mode. Now connect your Nexus 7 to your computer via USB, open a command terminal and type `fastboot devices`, and hit enter. If your computer recognizes the device, the terminal will output the serial number and fastboot.

The next step will wipe all data off of the device. If that's ok, continue.

Now, type in `fastboot oem unlock` and hit enter. The device will prompt you to confirm the bootloader unlock. Follow the instructions on the Nexus 7 to unlock the bootloader. When finished, the terminal will display a success message. After this is complete, type `fastboot reboot-bootloader` and hit enter to refresh the bootloader.

Now, move the image zip to the `platform-tools` folder of the Android SDK and unpack the factory image on your computer using whatever zip tool you have available. There is a second zip file inside the package, be sure to unzip that also. then, in the terminal, navigate to the unzipped factory image folder and type `./flash-all.sh` (OSX/Linux) or `flash-all.bat` (Windows) depending on your computer's operating system.

Let it do its thing and the device should boot into the OS when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The app's file has been modified in some way, changed or removed. Look up your build number in settings and search for it on Google. Hopefully you'll find a zip with .img files in it. If you've got the correct img files, reflash system.img and you're able to flash the ota.